# update_callback not calling proper function when sending post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

So, here's my code so far:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'rest_api_user_meta_fields' );

function rest_api_user_meta_fields() {
    // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field( 'user', 'grad', array(
           'get_callback'       => 'get_user_acf_fields',
           'update_callback'    => 'update_user_acf_fields',
           'schema'             => null,
        )
    );
}

function get_user_acf_fields( $object ) {
    //get the id of the post object array
    $grad = get_field('grad', 'user_32');
    error_log($object);
    return $grad;
}

function update_user_acf_fields( $value, $object, $field_name ) {
    error_log($value);
    error_log($field_name);
    error_log($object);
}
```

Now, I expect to have `get_user_acf_fields` function to be executed when I send GET request to `/users/` endpoint, and `update_user_acf_fields` to be run when I send POST request to said endpoint. In both cases it executes former, `get_user_acf_fields`, function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you didn't include the proper *nonce*?

> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be
>   passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to
>   `wp_rest`. These can then be passed to the API via the `_wpnonce` data
>   parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via
>   the `X-WP-Nonce` header. *If no nonce is provided the API will set the
>   current user to 0, turning the request into an **unauthenticated
>   request**, **even if you’re logged into WordPress**.*

— Read more on https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Here's your code that I modified and tested working on WordPress 4.9.5 with Advanced Custom Fields 4.4.12.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'rest_api_user_meta_fields' );

function rest_api_user_meta_fields() {
    // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field( 'user', 'grad', array(
           'get_callback'       => 'get_user_acf_fields',
           'update_callback'    => 'update_user_acf_fields',
           'schema'             => [
             'description' => 'User grad blah',
             'type'        => 'string',
           ],
        )
    );
}

// $user_arr is an `array` of the user data; e.g. `id`, `username`, and `name`.
// $field_name is the name of the ACF custom field; i.e. in this case, it's `grad`.
function get_user_acf_fields( $user_arr, $field_name ) {
    // Get the value of the 'grad' custom field.
    $grad = get_field($field_name, 'user_' . $user_arr['id']);
    error_log(var_export( $user_arr, true ));
    error_log($field_name);
    //return $grad;
    return $field_name . ';' . $grad . ';' . $user_arr['id'];
}

// $field_value is the value of the ACF custom field; i.e. in this case, it's `grad`.
// $user_obj is an `object` of the user data; e.g. `id`, `username`, and `name`.
function update_user_acf_fields( $field_value, $user_obj, $field_name ) {
    // Get the value of the 'grad' custom field.
    $grad = get_field($field_name, 'user_' . $user_obj->ID);

    if ( $grad !== $field_value ) {
      update_field( $field_name, $field_value, 'user_' . $user_obj->ID );
    }

    error_log($field_value);
    error_log($field_name);
    error_log(var_export( $user_obj, true ));

    return true;
}
```

And [here's the HTML and JS/AJAX](https://pastebin.com/WQuPU8mG) I used for testing the PHP code above.

Comment: *// $user_obj is an `object` of the user data; e.g. `id`, `username`, and `name`.* - `$user_obj` is actually an instance of the `WP_User` `class`.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET, $_POST and UPDATE are different things to the rest API. Since update isn't necessarily a construct of the language it just means that when a request usually a $_POST comes in with a specific "Update" header that it should call your update function.

Comment: UPDATE isn't really an method. This said, I've studied the WP-REST API a lot, and I couldn't find anything pointing to a special UPDATE like param in the request header that needs to be set in order to actually update over creating. This said, only thing similar to this is a regular POST parameter 'context', and I made sure it's set to edit. If I misunderstood, please point me to a documentation page that contains info on how should I form request header. Ie, please let me know how exactly can I do this to test out.